# how to enter 2 chars in one comand in C++

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    long long x,y,z,result;
    char f,g;
    cin >>x>>y>>z;
    **result** = 
    cout << result ;
    return 0;
}
```

How to make result = x (+ or - or / or *) y (+ or - or / or *) z !?

Comment: `result = x + y + z;`  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the operators in between the numbers is simple:

```
long long x,y,z;
char f,g;
cin >>x>>f>>y>>g>>z;
// See what you've got
cout << x << " " << f << endl;
cout << y << " " << g << endl;
cout << z endl;
```

However, figuring out the result of the operation is trickier: you need to check the values you've got in `f` and `g`, and perform the operations as needed. Note that there must be no space between your numbers and the operators, otherwise the input would be processed incorrectly.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/WfCVjW)

This is probably at the core of the exercise that you are solving, so I will suggest that you write a function like this:

```
long long compute(long long a, long long b, char op) {
    ... // Check the operator, and return the result
}
```

With this function in hand, you can produce the result in one simple call:

```
long long result = compute(compute(x, y, f), z, g);
```

Once you write the `compute` function, this should give the result that you expect.

Comment: @AmrMorsy Your input should look like this: `12345+678*91011`, not like this: `12345 + 678 * 91011`. Otherwise, the space would get into `f`, and `z` would not read at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can do cin>>astring. And separate the string by delimiter and convert them to integer.

For example: 
1,2,3
will become '1','2','3'.